# Unbounded inverse of a bounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, unbounded-operators

Suppose that $T\in B(H)$. As we know $T^{-1}$ is bounded if and only if $T$ is bijective. Also, $T^{-1}T=TT^{-1}=I$. In the other word, $T^{-1}:\mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H}$ such that $T^{-1}T\xi=\xi$ for every $\xi\in \mathcal{H}$.

How is the inverse (unbounded inverse) of $T$ defined if $T$ is not boundedly invertible?

Comment: its defined on a dense subset, which is why an unbounded operator's definition always includes the domain explicitly

Comment: @CalvinKhor Please more give information. How is $T^{-1}$ defined on $R(T)^\perp$??

Comment: I don't understand your example $T$. You also shouldnt expect every bounded operator to have an inverse, even if you allow it to be unbounded. E.g. $T\equiv 0$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you. It was my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defined on a dense subset. The typical example is $T $ given by $Te_n=\frac1n\,e_n $. Then $T^{-1}e_n=ne_n $, and so $T^{-1} $ is only defined on a dense subset of $H $.

Comment: How would such  $T $ be an operator?